# Implementing a robust and efficient RPC system

Tags: networking, rpc

I need to have a server which is able to call functions on the client. I always used RPC's in different networking game API's but I never implemented it by myself.

How would I do it?

My naive approach would be:

connect client to the server:

server

```
fn update_position_client(){
 unique_id = 1;
 send.to_client(unique_id);
}
```

client

```
while recv_messages {
  if id == 1
    update_position();
}
```

Is this how I would do it?

Comment: I would avoid implementing it myself, particularly as a beginner! That stuff is complicated, and there are surely tons of good libraries. But maybe you're doing this just for fun/learning, then I guess there is a point to doing it yourself.

Comment: @Jolta I am using a new language called Rust which does not have any RPC support. Should I just wrap a RPC c library? If yes could you recommend me any?

Comment: Aha, so you ARE doing it just for fun then. ;-)
I haven't got much experience of network programming in C so I will leave this up to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you only have a few messages that you want to send, and if the data basically known.  To be more robust, you would want to have the ability to dynamically add/remove messages that can be called, and figure out how to look up the methods to be called when RPC is called.

Assuming you want this to be completely transparent to the user, what typically happens in this case is that when the a message is sent, the RPC library will wait until there's a response back.  Assuming bi-directional capabilities, what normally happens is that there's a single thread that listens for data.  If an RPC message comes in, this thread will figure out what to do with the message, i.e. what method to call in your(local) address space and with what parameters you want to call it with.  When you send an RPC message out, the thread that you sent the message out on is blocked(probably with a semaphore) until the return message comes back, at which point your local thread is unblocked and allowed to continue.

A Linux-specific RPC library you could look at would be DBus.